# Technically, is a comma between an attributive adjective and a noun acceptable?

Tags: commas

1. There's a, handsome, boy.
2. Yellow, butterflies fly away.

Comment: Grammatically incorrect it seems. __There's a handsome boy [...].__ and __Yellow butterflies fly away.__

Comment: But 'yellow, small dogs' is correct.

Comment: If they are dyed yellow.

Comment: `Yellow, small dogs`. That's because the comma is separating **two adjectives** or **an adjective and an adjunct noun**. Comma is used to separate list items. Though it is not the only use, it is one of the uses of the punctuation.

Comment: Technically you could argue that *a, handsome" can work if *a* is working as an adjective, in the sense of stressing "one, singular" - so you might run across something like this (probably more likely in speech, with audible commas). But that's @DhanishthaGhosh 's rule applied to an unusual situation (where *a* isn't just acting as an article)